# Testing ios program on real phone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

I'm doing my assignment about mobile devices. I used to use android in this course but I don't have any android devices for this assignment.

I was suggested by my lecturer that I can use iphones to finish this assignment. I've got a starter 'hello world' program, it works fine on ios simulators. I've entered my apple id in the preference and put myself in the team option on the project general.

I got a yellow sign telling me:

> No provision profiles found
>   No non-expired provisioning profiles were found

If I click the `fix issue` button, it ends with this:

> An App ID with Identifier 'comp.Test1' is not available. Please enter a different string.

So do I have to purchase the apple developer program to run this helloworld on my phone (which is unlikely cause I'm just doing it for assignment) or is there a fix to this issue? Thank you.

*My Xcode version is 7.3.1

Comment: yes, you`have to purchase the apple developer program`. It is required to upload and test your applications on real devices

Comment: No, you have to join the Apple Developer program, but you can now install your app to your own device without buying a paid membership.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your reply. I got a free membership following [link](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/12/24/how-to-create-a-free-apple-developer-account-xcode/) but I'm still having the same issue while installing the app to my device

Comment: you can also think of join the iOS Developer University Program, it is free and have many resources https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/university/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your bundle id to something else. Currently your bundle id is "comp.Test1" try using something which is unique and would have not been used by anyone else. 
Suggestions : "com.mycollegeproject.test.iosapp"

To change your bundle id just select your project name in left side menu
select the general tab and inside that you will find textbox where you can change your bundle identifier

Comment: @SuperMurloc please mark the answer as accepted. This will make it easier to find the correct answer, if somebody has the same problem

Comment: Best of luck :)

Answer (score -2):

1.In Xcode, add your Apple ID to Accounts preferences, described in Adding Your Apple ID Account in Xcode.

2.In the project navigator, select the project and your target to display the project editor.

3.Click General and choose your name from the Team pop-up menu.

4.Connect the device to your Mac and choose your device from the Scheme toolbar menu.

5.Below the Team pop-up menu, click Fix Issue.

6.Xcode creates a free provisioning profile for you and the warning text under the Team pop-up menu disappears.

7.Click the Run button.

Xcode installs the app on the device before launching the app.

Comment: no. This was changed in Xcode 7. You don't need to enroll the Developer Program anymore